# Best way to overload an operator comparing properties

Tags: python, pandas, properties, operator-overloading

I was wondering if there was a way to overload in python3 an operator when it is comparing properties of a class? My properties are 1-long panda.Series (yes, this seems stupid but I need it when dealing with a large number of objects) and I would like to be able to use these properties with list comprehensions without calling the `item()` method (for API readability).

Example:

```
class Signal(object):

    @property
    def halftime(self):
        return pd.Series(whatever_with_len_eq_1)
```

What works:

```
signals = [Signal(a), Signal(b), Signal(c)]
best_signals = [sig for sig in signals if sig.halftime.item() > 25]
```

What I would like to work:

```
signals = [Signal(a), Signal(b), Signal(c)]
best_signals = [sig for sig in signals if sig.halftime > 25]
```

However, direct comparison of 1-term series and float/int is not authorized by pandas. So I was wondering if there was a way to overload properties comparison (ex `@halftime.__geq__`, but a quick research in SO showed that it is unlikely); or in what directions should I go: overloading panda.Series comparison methods? Make a wrapper (but I can't see one that would be able to "convert" my data when comparing but not when directly called)?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Any reason it is a 1-value series vs. a simple scalar? Even if the underlying data is a series the `halftime` property could return the value.

Comment: Create another `class` for the halftime attribute and write the `__gt__` method for it to do what you'd like.

Comment: @AChampion, the reason is that I never deal with only one Signal object, but with loads of them. The Series has as index the reference of the signal and as name the unit of it, which allows for other classes to quickly concatenate and export all the data without losing what is what. However it is probably a bad implementation (as I can see now...) and I should see how to deal differently with my data.